# Using header to build url in http outbound channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I'm consuming messages from a rabbit queue with a bean configured like so:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundGateway(listenerContainer()).errorChannel(FailedFlow.CHANNEL_NAME))
            .transform(Transformers.fromJson())
            .channel(TestFlow.CHANNEL_NAME)
            .get();
```

The message goes through some routers and header enrichers to end up in an outbound flow with a bean configured like so:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(CHANNEL_NAME)
            .transform(Transformers.toJson())
            .handle(Http.outboundChannelAdapter("http://localhost:8080/api/test")
                            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                            .requestFactory(getRequestFactory()))
            .get();
```

This works fine while testing, but for actual use i need to send the request to different servers using a base url stored in a header that has been added earlier.

```
IntegrationFlows.from(CHANNEL_NAME)
            .transform(Transformers.toJson())
            .handle(e -> Http.outboundChannelAdapter(String.format("%s/test",
                    e.getHeaders().get(IntegrationConstants.NOTIFY_BASE_URL_HEADER_NAME)))
            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
            .requestFactory(getRequestFactory()))
            .get();
```

It seems that in the test config i'm passing a MessageHandlerSpec to the handle method and in the actual config i'm passing a MessageHandler to the handle method. I'm not sure what does the difference, all i know is that the endpoint is not called when passing the MessageHandler.

How do i access the headers while maintaining the direct use of the MessageHandlerSpec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.handle(IntegrationFlows.from(CHANNEL_NAME)
                    .transform(Transformers.toJson())
                    .handle(Http.outboundChannelAdapter("{baseUrl}/test")
                            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                            .requestFactory(getRequestFactory())
                            .uriVariable("baseUrl", e -> e.getHeaders().get(IntegrationConstants.NOTIFY_BASE_URL_HEADER_NAME)))
                    .get())
```

:-D